# Vee-validate child date-picker component

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I am trying to write validate to my custom components using vee-validate   (vue version 2.5.3, vee-validate version 2.1.0-beta.7). Everything works fine except that fact that none of my datepickers pass validation.

**PARENT.VUE**

```
template(v-for="(item, index) in items")
  div(class="initials")
    edit-date-field(:date="item.start"
                    :date_errors="errors.collect('start[' + index + ']')"
                    :name="startDate"
                    :data-vv-name="'start[' + index + ']'"
                    v-validate="'required'"
                    @date-picker="updateDate(item, 'start', $event)"
                    data-vv-as="date"
                    )
   edit-date-field(:date="item.end"
                   :date_errors="errors.collect('end[' + index + ']')"
                   :name="endDate"
                   :data-vv-name="'end[' + index + ']'"
                   v-validate="'required'"
                   data-vv-as="date"
                   @date-picker="updateDate(item, 'end', $event)")
 v-flex(xs12 sm12 md10 pa-2)
   v-text-field(
              slot="input"
              label="College"
              v-model="item.name"
              :error-messages="errors.collect('college[' + index + ']')"
              v-validate="'required'"
              :data-vv-name="'college[' + index + ']'"
              data-vv-as="college name"
              )
 v-flex(xs12 sm12 md10 pa-2)
   v-text-field(
              slot="input"
              label="Degree"
              v-model="item.degree"
              :error-messages="errors.collect('degree[' + index + ']')"
              v-validate="'required'"
              :data-vv-name="'degree[' + index + ']'"
              data-vv-as="degree"
              )
v-btn(v-if="!item.id" color="primary" @click="create(item)" depressed small) Save
```

**CHILD.VUE**

```
<template lang="pug">
  v-layout(row wrap)
    v-flex(xs12 sm9)
      v-menu(
            ref='menu'
            lazy
            :close-on-content-click='false'
            transition='scale-transition'
            offset-y=''
            full-width
            :nudge-right='40'
            min-width='290px'
            )
        v-text-field(
                    slot="activator"
                    v-model='datePicker'
                    :error-messages="date_errors"
                    :label='name'
                    prepend-icon='event'
                    readonly
                    )
        v-date-picker(
                   v-model='datePicker'
                   color="indigo"
                   min='1950-01-01'
                   max='2020-01-01'
                   @input="updateDate(datePicker)"
                   )
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    menu: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    date: {
      type: String
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date_errors: {},
  },
   data() {
     return {
       datePicker: this.date
     }
   },
   methods: {
     updateDate(value) {
       this.$refs.menu.save(value);
       this.$emit('date-picker', value)
     }
   }
};
</script>
```

So my college and degree validations work fine, but edit-date-field not. I tried to put my code to codesandbox but without success. I attach gif I made to provide more information. Thanks in advance. [Gif](http://g.recordit.co/3glKTTo7t2.gif)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty bad in searching... Author of VeeValidate made this amazing demo for us:
[Component + datepicker demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/2wyrp5z000?from-embed)

The main point was to get proper value from datepicker.

Comment: A more up to date example ( though not specifically aimed at datepickers but equally applicable to them) by the same author can be found here https://codesandbox.io/s/9l7r2mlxwy. This can be also be cross referenced in the following github link https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/1896

Comment: Thanks, Ken. Despite of outdating of mu issue I will take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to validate whole component, and it has no means to determine if it is filled or not.

Try transmitting validation rules through props.
For example:

**In a parent**

```
edit-date-field(:date="item.start"
                :date_errors="errors.collect('start[' + index + ']')"
                :name="startDate"
                :data-vv-name="'start[' + index + ']'"
                :required="true"
                @date-picker="updateDate(item, 'start', $event)"
                data-vv-as="date"
                )
```

**In a child**

```
    v-text-field(
                slot="activator"
                v-model='datePicker'
                v-validate="required ? 'required' : ''"
                :error-messages="date_errors"
                :label='name'
                prepend-icon='event'
                readonly
                )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. However it didn't help. I put everything inside child component but it doesn't work at all.